# Add Input of Type File to a Form Dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, file, upload

I'm working on an drag n drop functionality. I have the code that I need to catch the file when it's dropped on my drop area, but I'm have some issues to send it for xmlhttprequest since I cant send through jQuery or ajax.

I'm now thinking about a hidden iFrame, but I don't really know how I can attach this file, that I already have, thanks to the user drop, to an existing form.

```
var droparea = $('#dropzone');
    var uploadButon = $('#upload');
    droparea.on('dragover',function(){
        $(this).addClass('dragover');
        return false;
    });
    droparea.on('dragleave',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('dragover');
        return false;
    });
    droparea.on('drop', function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).removeClass('dragover');
       var files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

       var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);

            for( var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i ) {
                var file = files[i];
                formData.append("files[]", file);
            }

            return $.ajax({
                url: "upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(text) {
                    alert(text);
                }

            });

    });

            //the php

           <?php
             echo count($_FILES["files"]);
                for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["files"]["name"]) ; $i++)
                {
              if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i],                               "upload/".$_FILES["files"]["name"][$i]))
                echo "ok";
                   else
                echo "no";
                 }
            ?>
```

Comment: That should work, assuming `$('userDropedFile')` is targeting a file input. However, if you're using drag-n-drop file upload, why not go a little further and also implement xhr file upload rather than using an iframe if it's available?

Comment: Why is the file input not inside the form in the first place?

Comment: edit, now working ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that the element

```
$("#userDroppedFile")
```

Is your drop area.

That's not how you get the file though, you get it in the drop event:

```
$("#userDroppedFile").on("drag dragend dragenter dragleave dragover dragstart drop", function(e){
    var files;
    e.preventDefault();

    if( e.type === "drop" && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer ) {
        files = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    }

    if( !files || !files.length ) {
        return;
    }

    doUpload(files);

});
```

In doUpload you take [form data from your static html form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), and add the files into it and upload:

```
function doUpload(files) {

    var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);

    for( var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i ) {
        var file = files[i];
        formData.append("file" + (i+1), file);
    }

    return $.ajax({
        url: "xx",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function() {
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: no, i tried to simply thins, thast my drop area, but im catching the file, if you want i cant post all the code, but assuming that i already have the file, how can i attach it to a form. thanks for the fast answer, ill try!

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasRoca I am showing how to attach it to a form in the `doUpload` function.. you cannot attach a file to the normal form, you can only use ajax to upload it unfortunately.

Comment: thats even better, ive already tried that and the php that upload the files its still receiving an empty $_FILES

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasRoca there could be a problem using file.name as the file entry key. I will edit a possible fix, other than that I don't know without any debug information.

Comment: no, the file name its returning correctly the filename. ive updated to my real code. thanks.

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasRoca I see but there could be a million unrelated reasons why `$_FILES` is empty. At the very least you should debug what is being sent over network in the Google Chrome Developer Tools Network tab.

Comment: @SantiagoNicolasRoca I also see that you have copypasted the code blindly... there are some things that require possible modification like `$("form")[0]`

Comment: no, i do have a form. just like that. thanks again. im debbugin to see the whats sent. thanks again

Comment: thanks thanks so much, it was my bad, the debbug was ok, the file was being sent, the problem was that:  formData.append(file.name, file);

Comment: For what its worth, I get "illegal invocation" when I try an append.

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 use `processData: false` and `contentType: false`

Comment: @Esailija Thanks!  I wasn't expecting a reply.  In my error message, there was a problem with a jquery .append, so I had thought it was my "formData.append" line that was causing it, but no, modifying the post as you prescribe fixed it! :-x :-x (both cheeks)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFile = $('userDropedFile');
```

Not a valid jQuery selector. Do you perhaps mean:

```
var myFile = $('#userDropedFile');
```